# How to process the data quickly?

Tags: mongodb, distributed-computing

We have 50GB (1 million documents) original data has been stored in MongoDB. I have to transform/process the data and transfer them to another database.

It takes about 30 mins to read, process and write, but we need to finish it in seconds/minutes.

What should I need to read the data as soon as possible, to iterate all the documents in seconds?

Comment: There could be lots of things, but you have given us so little to go on. It might be that you need better indexes to support your queries; or it might be that you need disks with faster IO, or it might be that you need to parallelise your processing across multiple servers; there's too many possibilities.

Comment: I think I should have a faster I/O or something like parallel I/O, so that I can access the document quickly. Because it takes almost 20mins to iterate all the document. Is it possible to iterate 50GB data in seconds?

Comment: Do you have any specific query that needs to be run on MongoDB or just want to transfer whole data?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) should work for your use case. 
[This](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) should help you to get started with Spark.

[This](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tutorial-for-operationalizing-spark-with-mongodb) and [this](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-mongodb) should help you to get started with MongoDb on Spark.

Now once your spark application is up, you need to scale it by running on some cluster. [This](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) should help you in that adventure.